# Creating a Comments section - Best approach?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-login, google-signin, messageboard

I want to create a comments section for pages on my website, and was wondering what is the best approach to adding one?

I don't want to use Wordpress because I think it is unnecessary for just implementing a comments section. The rest of my site is very basic. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

I can do it using PHP and MySQL. Is there an already documented best design for the DB schema used for comments?

Or I can use the facebook plugin. However I would also like to allow users to log in through their google accounts. Don't think the FB plugin supports that.

So what is the best way to do this, while allowing users to login (to post comments) using their FB or google login?

Comment: This is too broad and subjective a question.  Many ways to do this, but perhaps narrow down to whether you'll use a third party or host your own.  You don't have to drop in your own Php solution you could grab code and host your own.  It doesn't have to be Php either.  You could link to forum software, with each post as a topic.  All depends on your requirements and tastes.  I shy away from third party systems, or systems that make me jump through a hoop just to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" is often depending on very personal requirements, which you did not specify. If you want to practice programming, or play with some server-side programming, maybe do a little "dynamic HTML", then you want to do your own thing with PHP and MySQL, or another technology that you want to learn and can deploy for your website (though PHP+MySQL is the most common stack you can deploy to).

If you are going that route, then I suggest looking at PHP frameworks that offer an ORM. I personally like [Kohana](https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships), but [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/intro.html) looks like a good candidate as well and and it's a bit more modern. Take a look at the ORM examples in the links - they offer hints on how to design the model, which is basically how the database schema will look. If you're not familiar with ORM, you might want to review the [Wikipedia article on ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

To get people to log in with Google authentication, you'd need to learn about federated authentication and its various protocols. Google uses OpenID Connect (which is an OAuth 2 extension), while Facebook like to use their own protocol (Facebook Login) but can also support the standard OAuth 2. There are several libraries that will help you implement these protocols, though I like to use ["The League"'s packages](https://packagist.org/search/?q=league%2Foauth). You might want to learn about [PHP composer](https://getcomposer.org/) by the way.

If you're not into writing code that you'd then need to deploy and maintain, and would prefer to get all the bells and whistles out of the box with minimal effort, you might want to look at [Disqus](https://disqus.com/).